# gdal_contour: Specifying index contour lines

Tags: gdal, dem, contour, gdal-contour

I'm building an application where I need to programmatically generate contour lines(and export to a .dxf) from a raster terrain data-set(DTM specifically).

**What I've tried:** Using [gdal_contour](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_contour.html), I've been able to generate contour lines with a specific fixed interval from the DTM.

**Where I need help:** In addition to the regular contour lines generated at every X meter, I want an index(or major) contour line generated at every Y meter, where X and Y can be any positive elevation value. I know how to use gdal_contour to generate just one set of contour lines at fixed intervals but lost on how to include the index contour lines in the result.

Say I want to generate a contour dataset with minor(the regular) lines at every 5m and a major(or index) contour line at every 10meters, how do I achieve this with gdal_contour?

I'm open to using other tools or libraries that can be called programmatically via CLI or code import(I'm using NodeJS).

Comment: Take the result and use the modulo operator (in your GIS software's field calculator, Node.JS, or whatever) to see if the elevation value is evenly divisible by your index interval

Comment: Since you specifically mention .dxf as the output format, the dxf driver supports defining a pen (width, color, dash-pattern). You would use gdal_contour to write two .dxf files, one with the minor lines and styling, the second with major lines and styling.

Comment: Thanks @mikewatt. But unfortunately, I'm trying to programmatically generate the result, so opening it file in GIS software is not an option.

Comment: Thanks @Llaves, writing two .dxf files is a work-around that kind of works but I'd still love to get a solution where I can have both contour line categories in a single file.

Comment: I simply gave a conceptual way to identify the index contours, you could implement that however you want.  With contours at a 5m interval, `elev % 10 == 0` will be true for 10m indexes